# How to make a ajax request using post method

Tags: ajax, django

I made an ajax request using post method in django..its wokring perfectly..the problem is its calling the complete html page rahter than a div..i want to call only a div..i tried but unable to find the exact solution..

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('#Category').change(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var e = document.getElementById("Category");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
$.ajax({
    url: "/charts/",
    type: "post",
     dataType: "html",
    data: value,
    success: function(data) {
  $('#div1').html(data);
    }});
 return false;
});
});
</script>
```

I want only div  content with id #div1..i already tried find and replace method

Comment: `$("#div1").replaceWith($(data).filter("#div1"))`

Comment: i already tries it..but not getting any content

Answer (score 0):

What is the nature of the event ? Is it a button ? an Input ?

If it is an input as `<input type="submit">`, the default action is to reload the page like a form.

Comment: Ok i am wrong i hadn't understand your problem. Maybe.

Comment: input type is select

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your div id is really div1?

$("#div1").append("your html code"+data+" your html code")

Comment: have you done console.log(data)?  check what's inside data. Maybe it's returning html. What are you returning from  your view associated with charts?

Comment: yes i checked its return complete html page..and i my view i use bokeh chart

Comment: what I would do, is to return json I'll post the next comment with an example

Comment: return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list), content_type = 'application/json')

Comment: list is a regular python list,but you can return more types, string for instance.
then they will be available in data variable in your ajax function, and you can use the specific values to edit #div1

Comment: html = render_to_string("myapp/dropdown.html", {'script': script,'div':div,})
    return HttpResponse(html)  this is what i have done in my views

Comment: what is script and div? Did you consider doing:

Comment: return HttpResponse(json.dumps([script,div]), content_type = 'application/json')

Comment: then data[0] will be script and data[1] will be div, I believe

Comment: no..actually i want to return render in html template